# rm -rf returning "rm: cannot remove 'PATH': Directory not empty"

Tags: kubuntu, ntfs, delete, trash, dolphin

I'm trying to delete a folder on an NTFS drive mounted to `/media/soup/ntfs_d/` but it's resulting in a some strange behavior.

For context,  a while ago I deleted some files via Dolphin which apparently put them in some kind of trash directory. When I tried to empty the trash via Dolphin, it resulted in an error saying it could not delete it.

That brings me to now, trying to `rm -rf` the directory of `/media/soup/ntfs_d/.Trash-1000/` with `sudo rm -rf /media/soup/ntfs_d/.Trash-1000`
which results in:

```
rm: cannot remove '/media/soup/ntfs_d/.Trash-1000/files/Halo Infinite/disk_cache/gamecmscache':   
Directory not empty
```

Searching on the internet for people with the same issue I've ended up empty-handed.

Specs:

OS: Kubuntu 23.10
  Shell: bash 5.2.15
  Terminal: konsole
  CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 5500 (12) @ 4.267GHz
  GPU: AMD ATI Radeon RX 6700/6700 XT/6750 XT / 6800M/6850M XT
  Memory: 5083MiB / 15847MiB

Comment: Would you please [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo bash -c 'type -a rm; rm --version'`

Comment: @Raffa that doesnt output anything for me

Comment: Try with setting the full path to Bash `sudo /bin/bash -c 'type -a rm; rm --version'` … and then run `sudo rm --version` .., Does those output anything now?

Comment: … Also, what’s the output of `echo $0; type -a rm; rm --version` without using `sudo`

Comment: This question already has answers [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/736596/134479) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/711913/134479).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get "Directory not empty" when I try to remove an empty directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/566474/why-do-i-get-directory-not-empty-when-i-try-to-remove-an-empty-directory)

Comment: Before you attempt any of the linked answers and for pure science, please run `sudo strace rm -rf /media/soup/ntfs_d/.Trash-1000` and add the output to your question … I would like to find out why this is happening.